# Is there a way to bypass varnish cache on client side?

Tags: python, http, varnish

I'm trying to fetch fresh content from a wordpress blog, and it uses varnish on server side. Is there a way to bypass varnish cache control so that I can get fresh content each time I request that site?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation claims that [Varnish will not cache any requests with a `Cookie` header](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/cookies.html), so a quick work around might be to include a `Cookie: …` header. Alternatively, you can include an un-used GET parameter like `?cachebuster=1234`, which should bypass caching.

Comment: Do note, that this method will fill up your cache. Also, if you're stripping them this won't work. Obviously :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, Everybody install `Varnish` on port 80 and change the default web service (`Apache`, `Nginx` or etc...) to listen on 8080.

So, Add the port 8080 to bypass Varnish:

```
Example: www.example.com:8080
```